# Get row number data frame R

Tags: r

I have a dataset like this

```
   epoch epochIndex year month
1     335          1 1850    12
2     639          2 1851    10
3     670          3 1851    11
4     366          4 1851     1
5     517          5 1851     6
6     547          6 1851     7
7     578          7 1851     8
8    1005          8 1852    10
9    1036          9 1852    11
10   1066         10 1852    12
```

What I would like to do is to set the Year and Month and get the correspondent row number, like

```
MONTH <- 12
YEAR <- 1850

ROWNUMBER = 1
```

Many thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A simple `which` call would be enough, e.g.:

```
df <- read.table(textConnection("
   epoch epochIndex year month
1     335          1 1850    12
2     639          2 1851    10
3     670          3 1851    11
4     366          4 1851     1
5     517          5 1851     6
6     547          6 1851     7
7     578          7 1851     8
8    1005          8 1852    10
9    1036          9 1852    11
10   1066         10 1852    12"), header=TRUE)

which(df$year == 1850 & df$month == 12)
# [1] 1

which(df$year == 1852 & df$month == 12)
# [1] 10
```

Answer (score 1):

Sorry I found the answer

```
TIMEC <- which(df$year==YEAR & df$month==MONTH)
```

Comment: Considering that you posted this *after* an answer had been posted by a member of the community, and considering that this is essentially the same answer, I would suggest deleting it.